# Can I change my language to English?

Tags: language

I created my account and first blog while waiting at the airport in Switzerland. Now my admin page and blog are in German! I can't understand what most of it means, so I can't seem to be able to switch it back to English.

Please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **Einstellungen/Allgemein/Sprache der Seite** (`wp-admin/options-general.php`) and select **English**. Then click the Button **Änderungen übernehmen**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the version 4.0 or above just go to Settings > general > Site Language and choose your desired language.

You can find more information in [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Chrome.
[image: Google Chrome Browser]

And using the built-in Google Translator you can translate your non-English web page or admin panel to a readable format at least.

#### Step 1:

In your German (non-English Google Translate Supported language) web page/admin panel click on to the Translate button
[image: A site in German]

#### Step 2:

Hit the Translate button
[image: Hit the Translate button]

#### And, *Yala!*

[image: and your page is translated]

Then you can easily change the language to English from **Settings** » **General** » at the very bottom of the page **Site Language**.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the wordpress language is not a difficult task. You can make changes through your wordpress dashboard. Follow these steps to [change language in wordpress](https://www.wpblog.com/changing-wordpress-website-language/)  :

1- Login to your Wordpress dashboard

2- Go to settings then general which is basically in german Allgemein

[image]

3- Then sprache der seite which is site language and select english and when once done select save changes.